# How can I populate a table's cell through JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table as below. I have to populate the "Amount" field using the "Buy Quantity" and "Market Price" field. Amount = Buy Quantity*Market Price. I am doing something as -

```
<script>
function populate() {
var rows = document.getElementById("mytable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
for ( var i = 1; i <= rows.length; i++) {
    cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for ( var j = 0; j <= cells.length; j++) {
        if (j == 1) {
            var num1 =parseFloat(cells[1].childNodes[0].value);
            var num2 =parseFloat(cells[2].childNodes[0].data);
            var num3=num1 * num2;
            cells[3].childNodes[0].value = num3.toString();
        }
     }
   }
 }
</script>
```

I can get the values of column1 and column2, but the value in last column is not getting populated. The last line does not seem to work.

```
cells[3].childNodes[0].value = num3.toString();
```

What should I change?

[image: myTable]

The below html code is part of my .jsp file.

```
 <form action="BuyServlet">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" id="mytable">
        <tr>
            <th>Stock Name</th>
            <th>Buy Quantity</th>
            <th>Market Price</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Stock Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity" onblur="populate()"></td>
            <td>122</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="amount">
            </d>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Stock Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity" onblur="populate()"></td>
            <td>111</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="amount"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have some HTML to go with that JavaScript?

Comment: Are you sure `cells[2].childNodes[0].data` works?

Comment: Always better to show code than an image.

Comment: Also there is no reason to loop through the cells!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is in need of improvement. In your table, you should have a thead and a tbody sections. This will make it more accessible and easier to ingore the heading row.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" id="mytable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Stock Name</th>
            <th>Buy Quantity</th>
            <th>Market Price</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Stock Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity"></td>
            <td>122</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="amount"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Stock Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quantity"></td>
            <td>111</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="amount"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Now with the code, you should be adding the onblur with code, not hardcoded. You are looping through the cells, there is no reason for that. Also there is no need to loop every row when the table is changed. Just calculate the one that changed! Using childNodes can be tricky because of whitespace differences in browsers. Run this code after the table has been rendered.

```
(function () {

    var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
    var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");​​​​​​​​​

    function populateRow (index, addBlurEvent) {
        var row = rows[index];
        var cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td")
        var textboxes = row.getElementsByTagName("input");

        var amountTextbox = textboxes[0];
        var totalTextbox = textboxes[1];
        var costCell = cells[2];

        var amount = amountTextbox.value.length>0 ? parseFloat(amountTextbox.value) : 0;
        var cost = parseFloat(costCell.innerHTML);
        var total = amount * cost;
        totalTextbox.value = total;

        if (addBlurEvent) {
            amountTextbox.onblur = function () { populateRow(index, false); };
        }

    }

    for (i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
        populateRow(i, true);    
    }

}());
```

The [running fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLvTT/) of the above code
​

Comment: Your solution seems great, but an issue I am facing. When I copied the codes from fiddle, the html did not produce the same result. The amount field is not getting updated. But in the fiddle its works fine. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Did you change the table to have thead and tbody? Does the page have any errors? Are you calling it onload or after the table is rendered?

Comment: Yes my table now has thead and tbody. No error. Calling it after the table is rendered. Still not working. Can I share the whole code with you somewhere, so that you could take a look?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you are getting the value from the text box (best quantity) and you are using data to get the value of the Market price(better use innerText)

try this (Replace with your code inside loop)

```
var num1 =parseFloat(cells[1].childNodes[0].value);
var num2 =parseFloat(cells[2].innerText);
var num3=num1 * num2;
cells[3].innerText = num3.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is due to spelling mistake - you have childnodes instead of childNodes on "cells[3].childnodes[0].value = num3.toString();"

Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/VwU7C/

Comment: I checked it with childNode too, but it does not work that way. Sudhakar's solution is working fine.